# How to invoke the android keyboard using JavaScript without a text field?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

So I copied one of my small JavaScript games to my android phone and ran it in the browser. The game worked fine, except one fatal flaw: The game requires keyboard input, and it doesn't have a text field.

The game requires the user to type in certain letters, but they don't type it into a text field. I use a keydown event listener to get each key and process it accordingly.

So how do I invoke the android keyboard without having an actual text field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <style>
        *
        {
            padding :0;
            margin  :0;
        }
        html, body
        {
            width  :100%;
            height :100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute;top:-1000px;left:-1000px">
        <input type="text" id="text">
    </div>
    <script>
        document.body.onclick=function()
        {
            console.log("here");
            var elem=document.getElementById("text");
            elem.focus()
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```